# SSL Certificate Doesn't Work With Path Parameters

Tags: ssl, url, web-hosting, cname, godaddy-api

I have a domain purchased from godaddy, that maps to a site hosted on AWS amplify. Amplify provides free SSL certs, but unfortunately godaddy doesn't allow ANAME records, so I had to buy a godaddy cert for the base domain (example.com). The AWS cert handled the www subdomain (www.example.com).
I also have a rule on godaddy forwarding example.com -> www.example.com

when I navigate to https://example.com/path, I get a warning in my browser saying it is unsafe.

However if I navigate to any of: https://www.example.com, https://example.com, https://www.example.com/path, OR http://example.com/path (HTTP not HTTPS), it will work fine.
In the case of the http, if I look at it in the browser after navigating to it, it shows as secure, and has been changed to https. However if I directly try to navigate to https://example.com/path, it doesn't work.

How can I solve this? Did godaddy scam me $60 and not actually give me an SSL cert? I suspect the "https://example.com" only works because of my forwarding rule to www, and that the forwarding rule doesn't work when there is a path parameter. 
Thanks

Comment: You can get free SSL with Let's encrypt, Never fall for GoDaddy's traps. It is unreasonably expensive and they will try to sell you things that are available for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godaddy does not support SSL over forwarding. I was using forwarding, which means godaddy set up an nginx forwarding server with HTTP only. I was forced to make a standalone server of my own to handle SSL certs, and just route all godaddy traffic through that, to my amplify site.

Luckily, godaddy was willing to refund the certificate.

Further info on godaddy not supporting this: https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Forwarding-from-HTTPS/m-p/126407/highlight/true#M24509